# Excavator has yet another problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Seems that the dupe-badging has been fixed. An unnoticed problem is, since that moment the badges still say that the post is unavailable, even if the badge obtained seemingly legit.

For example, see the [Excavator badge on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator):

> [image]

Comment: Probably I'm wrong with posting this question and not alerting in the previous one; just tell me that please and I remove this one.

Comment: Ah sorry with that, I should've mentioned it's the screenshot from SO, but it's the network-wide problem.

Comment: On other sites there's only one or two, so not really a problem. (So maybe better fit on MSO?)

Comment: @Sha I don't understand how one or two are not a problem. Yes, it's not so major, but it's the problem which is identical across all the SE sites. SO is just a good example to illustrate it. It's not the majority of a problem that matters, but a fact that it is a problem. Surely the users who got those badges are not really upset...

Comment: The script has stopped recording the post ID into the database. All the newly awarded ones just have a null in that field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a reason ID oversight in the new system - I have already deployed a long-term fix and a data sync up for already granted badges. Thanks for the report!